# mean() and sum()/n() results do not match

Tags: r

I am working through R for Data Science exercises to teach myself R, and when trying to find different solutions to the same questions, I ran into a result that puzzled me.

I loaded the following packages:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)
```

The question is: Look at the number of cancelled flights per day (`flights` data set). Is there a pattern? Is the proportion of cancelled flights related to the average delay?

I found a solution that describes the pattern well:

```
flights %>%
 group_by(year, month, day) %>%
 summarize(cancelled = mean(is.na(arr_delay)) , avg_delay = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
 ggplot(mapping = aes(x = avg_delay, y = cancelled)) +
 geom_point(alpha=0.5) + 
 geom_smooth(se=FALSE)
```

The following code (exchanging `mean()`with `sum()/n()` for `cancelled` flights) gives exactly the same picture:

```
flights %>%
 group_by(year, month, day) %>%
 summarize(cancelled = sum(is.na(arr_delay))/n() , avg_delay = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
 ggplot(mapping = aes(x = avg_delay, y = cancelled)) +
 geom_point(alpha=0.5) + 
 geom_smooth(se=FALSE)
```

But when I do the same for `avg_delay`, the picture changes:

```
flights %>%
  group_by(year, month, day) %>%
  summarize(cancelled = sum(is.na(arr_delay))/n() , avg_delay = sum(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE)/n()) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = avg_delay, y = cancelled)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.5) + 
  geom_smooth(se=FALSE)
```

I would have expected all expressions to give the same result. My notion would be that the missing values are sometimes considered and sometimes not and thus the picture changes, but I lack the R knowledge to test for the difference. 
Can anyone advise what I need to do in order to clarify where the difference comes from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because using `mean` with `na.rm = TRUE` will only consider those rows that are not `NA`. So the length will not be equal to `n()`!

Consider e.g. in your last example, using

```
avg_delay = sum(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE)/sum(!is.na(arr_delay))
```

Will yield exactly the same as the two methods above

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and this is indeed confirming what I already anticipated. I just did not come up with the idea to replace the n().